# MySQL - Getting wrong table fields with UNION ALL but results is correct

Tags: mysql, sql, union-all

I am trying to find records from two tables with by matching with email filed. Now results are getting correct but getting wrong table fields.

**Brand Table:**

```
brand_id    business_email              password
--------    --------------              --------
2           mack@gmail.com              ********
```

**Instagrammer Table:**

```
instagrammer_id     email                   password
---------------     -----                   --------
1                   manan@gmail.com         *********
```

and I have this mysql union query:

```
SELECT brand_id, business_email, password
FROM brand
WHERE business_email =  'manan@gmail.com'
AND STATUS =  '1'
UNION ALL 
SELECT instagrammer_id, email, password 
FROM instagrammer
WHERE email =  'manan@gmail.com'
AND STATUS =  '1'
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

and getting this result:

```
brand_id    business_email              password
--------    --------------              --------
1           manan@gmail.com             ********
```

Correct out is:

```
instagrammer_id     email                   password
---------------     -----                   --------
1                   manan@gmail.com         *********
```

Results are correct but table fields are wrong :( Any Idea how to solve this and get correct fields.

Comment: Just alias the first column to be `instagrammer_id` or reverse the order of the two subqueries.

Comment: That's what I first wanted to suggest - but i think the OP wants something else. 
@Mr. Happy - what would the column names be should the query return rows from both tables?

Comment: You can use ORDER BY clause to get second table column as ORDER BY 1 desc

Answer (score 0):

The column names for a `union`/`union all` query come from the first subquery.  You can use aliases to define them:

```
SELECT brand_id as instagrammer_id, business_email as email, password
FROM brand
WHERE business_email =  'manan@gmail.com'
AND STATUS =  '1'
UNION ALL 
SELECT instagrammer_id, email, password 
FROM instagrammer
WHERE email =  'manan@gmail.com'
AND STATUS =  '1'
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Alias in the first SELECT:

```
SELECT brand_id instagrammer_id, business_email email, password
FROM brand
WHERE business_email =  'manan@gmail.com'
AND STATUS =  '1'
UNION ALL 
SELECT instagrammer_id, email, password 
FROM instagrammer
WHERE email =  'manan@gmail.com'
AND STATUS =  '1'
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: but if I will try with `mack@gmail.com` I it will get `instagrammer_id` field which is wrong correct is `brand_id`

Comment: You have set fixed alias which is not perfect for me :(

Comment: but you cant change it for all. If both querys in the union give a result . So one FIELD = ONE FIELDNAME !!.  
The only thing is to add a new Column with the name from the sender:  

SELECT 'brand' sender,brand_id instagrammer_id, business_email email, password  
FROM brand  
WHERE business_email =  'manan@gmail.com'  
AND STATUS =  '1'  
UNION ALL   
SELECT 'instagrammer' sender, instagrammer_id, email, password   
FROM instagrammer  
WHERE email =  'manan@gmail.com'  
AND STATUS =  '1'  
LIMIT 0 , 30

Answer (score 0):

As i thought, you actually want the column names to change should your query only return rows from one table. But what if it returns rows from both?

I think the way to achieve your need (query both tables in a single statement yet know the source of the rows) is this:

```
SELECT brand_id as table_id, business_email as email, password, 'brand' as sourcetable
FROM brand
WHERE business_email =  'manan@gmail.com'
AND STATUS =  '1'
UNION ALL 
SELECT instagrammer_id, email, password, 'instagrammer'
FROM instagrammer
WHERE email =  'manan@gmail.com'
AND STATUS =  '1'
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

This way you have the name of the table from which the row comes as the value in the last column.